# Sending different types using same Rust channel (mpsc)

Tags: types, rust, channel

I've got a situation where I am setting up channel with multiple senders that need to be able to send different types of data to a receiving thread.

A receiving thread is created to handle these messages using the following match expression.

```
let receiver_thread = match config.style.as_str() {
    "Type1" => start_recv_type1(receiver, config.clone(), log.clone()),
    "Type2" => start_recv_type2(receiver, config.clone(), log.clone()),
    "Type3" => start_recv_type3(receiver, log.clone()),
    _ => panic!("Wrong type!"),
};
```

One possible type that can be send is a String while the other is a struct I've defined. However, the compiler is complaining about mismatched types on the receiving thread. Looking at how my receiver and sender is defined I can see why this is incorrect because it has the following type: `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<std::string::String>`.

Looking at my match expression, I think it's wiser to create a more generic function to initialize my receiving thread but how can I send different types of data over the same channel? I've searched and found a possible solution by using an enum that has my struct and a string as fields but does that mean I will have to change all my function definitions to use use this enum syntax? I.e. change my functions to use `ChannelTypes(StringMessage(String))` or `ChannelTypes(StructMessage(factory::datatype::MyStruct))`

```
enum ChannelTypes {
    StructMessage(factory::datatype::MyStruct),
    StringMessage(String),
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**One particular channel can only send one type of data.** As you noticed, your sender has the type `Sender<String>` and the receiver has the type `Receiver<String>`. So both are fixed on `String`. There is no way around this (for good reasons!)

**The preferred solution is actually to use an enum**, yes. In fact, you try to emulate what an enum would do for you: you have a *tag* that describes what kind of data to expect. In your attempt you use strings as tags. But that's a bad idea for a multitude of reasons. When you use an enum, integer tags (much better) are used and Rust handles them for you. Much more robust solution.

One suggestion: you might find it more useful to think of your enum type as message. As that's what it is: you send a message to another thread. And this message could be one of many different types. The receiving thread has to check which kind of message arrived and can then handle it.

Comment: `Enum` might be a problem if it's variants have considerable gap on memory size. Rust will allocate the largest size for the minimal variant also.

Comment: Yes, if there is a big discrepancy in sizes then you can `Box` the content of the message.

Comment: @ggovan That’s a good approach also, but probably i would go with Any.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, If I get you correctly I should just create an enum called, for example, MessageTypes and have 2 variants called MessageA and MessageB. Each variant is assigned to a single integer value by Rust and so every variant has the same size. But, how can I then use my 2 variants in functions? I need to get to the String or Vec<MyStruct> values within these enums. Do I have to write some methods with impl on this enum so I am able to interact with the underlying data? Would be great to have an example..

Comment: @Vinnie You would simply use `match` to match on the enum. Then you get access to the enclosed data. Not to be lazy, but [the book has a nice chapter on that](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html). I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, I was overthinking this one. For future references, I've wrapped my types (String, Vec<MyStruct>) into 2 enum variants. I use match on the receiving site to unwrap the enum and on the sending side I am creating batches of data that I wrap within an MessageType like so: `pub fn create_batch(timeseries: Vec<String>) -> Option<MessageType>`

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt if the enum was generic, ie, ``enum X<T> {....}`` can you make a single channel for the enum that applies to all variants? or do you have to make individual channels for that ``<T>``

Comment: @SamThomas You would have to make a channel per `T`. `X<u32>` is a different type than `X<String>`, so you have to use two channels.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt yeah i figured... kinda sucks.. but thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example with enum:

```
use std::sync::mpsc::{self, Receiver, Sender};

enum Fruit {
    Apple(u8),
    Orange(String)
}

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx): (Sender<Fruit>, Receiver<Fruit>) = mpsc::channel();

    tx.send(Fruit::Orange("sweet".to_string())).unwrap();
    tx.send(Fruit::Apple(2)).unwrap();

    for _ in 0..2 {
        match rx.recv().unwrap() {
            Fruit::Apple(count) => println!("received {} apples", count),
            Fruit::Orange(flavor) => println!("received {} oranges", flavor),
        }
    }
}

// output:
// received sweet oranges
// received 2 apples
```

Comment: Rust is so freaking nice. Nice solution!